# Geting the value of selecting dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Trying to get the value of selecting dropdown as below

```
<select id="utype" class="text" style="width:100%;padding:10px !important" name="user-type">
     <option value="default">Select </option>
     <option value="passenger">Passenger</option>
     <option value="driver">Driver</option>
</select>
```

but always the driver value is inseted into db even passenger is selected by user

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

     $date = date('Y-m-d');
     $full_name = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_REQUEST['fname']));
     $email_address = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_REQUEST['email']));
     $pass = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_REQUEST['password']));
     $contact_no = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_REQUEST['mobile']));
     $usertype = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_REQUEST['user-type']));
}
```

Also I tried to get usertype value in below 3 ways but still only driver value is inserted into DB.

```
1.$usertype = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user-type']);
2.$usertype= isset($_POST['user-type']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user-type']) : '';
3.$usertype=$_POST['user-type'];
```

even when I fix the usertype like $usertype = 'passenger'; and insert into db value $usertype .driver is inserted into db
here is the compelet php file

```
<?php
     include ('../includes/include_files.php');
     $msg = "";


 /* ----ON SUBMIT------ */


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$date = date('Y-m-d');

$full_name = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_REQUEST['fname']));
$email_address = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_REQUEST['email']));
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_REQUEST['password']));
$contact_no = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_REQUEST['mobile']));
$usertype = 'passenger';
// $usertype = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user-type']);
//$usertype= isset($_POST['user-type']) ?    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user-type']) : '';
//$usertype=$_POST['user-type'];
// $( "#utype" ).val();
// $("#elementId").val();
if($usertype='driver'){
    $status='Inactive';
}
else
{
    $status="Active";
}

if ($full_name != "" && $email_address != "" && $pass != "" && $contact_no != "" && $usertype != "") {

    $checkinfo = mysql_query("select * from tbl_user where email='" . $_POST['email'] . "' ");
    $count_email = mysql_num_rows($checkinfo);
    if ($count_email == 0) {

        $reg_ins = mysql_query("insert into tbl_user(`fullname`, `email`, `password`, `mobile`, `usertype`,`add_date`, `status` ) values ('$full_name','$email_address','$pass','$contact_no','$usertype','$date', '$status')");

        if ($reg_ins) {

            $uinfo = mysql_query("select * from tbl_user where email='" . $_POST['email'] . "' and password='" . $_POST['password'] . "' ");
            $res = mysql_fetch_object($uinfo);

            echo "<script>window.android.clickOnRegister();</script>";
        }
    } else {

        $msg = " Email ID Already Exist.";
    }
} else {

    $msg = "Please fill all required fields *";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: how are you passing data to php

Comment: Do you make the post via ajax or something special?

Comment: Your code is seems to be fine. May be you can try by changing name of your select box to user_type

Comment: standardway and php,js,html in one file

Comment: @DanielDudas  for form validatin we use ajax if this help

Comment: even when I fix the usertype like $usertype = 'passenger'; and insert into db value  $usertype .driver is inserted into db !!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @HadiSamadbin The problem is not with the `POST` is with `if($usertype='driver')`. I added an answer for this. Let me know if after that you still have problems.

Comment: @DanielDudas I really appreciate your help in resolving the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is at this line:

```
if($usertype='driver'){
```

Because you use only one `=` and you need to use double like this `==` to do a comparison. With one equal you asing to `$usertype` the value `driver`. (also it will always be free).

So change that line to:

```
if($usertype=='driver'){
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some special logic behind.

If you will send your form using standard way, you will get a proper value for `user-type` parameter.

Check if you have an unique `name="user-type"` within your form.

Check also what is the value sent to the server in firebug/chrome developer tools in order to determine if problem lies on backend or rather frontend side.

Comment: even when I fix the usertype like $usertype = 'passenger'; and insert into db value $usertype .driver is inserted into db !!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: The complete php file added to question

Comment: As you see you had some logic under the hood :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it:-

```
<select size="1" id="slt_country" name="country">
<option value=""> - Select - </option>
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="AL">Albania</option>
<option value="DZ">Algeria</option>

...

<option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
<option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

The Javascript code that can be used to get the user-selected country:

```
var selected_index = oForm.elements["country"].selectedIndex;

if(selected_index > 0)
{
   var selected_option_value = oForm.elements["country"].options[selected_index].value;
   var selected_option_text = oForm.elements["country"].options[selected_index].text;
}
else
{
   alert('Please select a country from the drop down list');
}
```

link:-http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-get-select.phtml